# onClick Button Text Change for the particular card using ID from REST API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, onclicklistener, buttonclick

Here, I'm trying to do integration for the RSVP button inside the card, onclicking the particular card the text inside the RSVP button should be changed to "Going" for the particular user ID below is my attached kindly help me with this problem...
Here, I'm trying to do integration for the RSVP button inside the card, onclicking the particular card the text inside the RSVP button should be changed to "Going" for the particular user ID below is my attached kindly help me with this problem...
Here, I'm trying to do integration for the RSVP button inside the card, onclicking the particular card the text inside the RSVP button should be changed to "Going" for the particular user ID below is my attached kindly help me with this problem...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './meetups.css';
import meetup_banner from '../../assets/images/scin_imgs/topbanner.jpg';
import Header from '../../containers/Header';


class MeetUps extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
           meetUpId: 0,
           meetups:[]
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getMeetups()
    }

    handleClick(id) {
    this.setState({
       meetUpId: id
    });
}

    getMeetups(){
          fetch('http://206.189.130.109:8000/api/v1/meetups/')
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => this.setState({meetups:data.results}))
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
         //console.log(this.state)

         fetch('http://206.189.130.109:8000/api/v1/meetups/rsvp/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({

                "id":this.state.meetups.id,
                "meetup_type": "meetup",
                "status": true,
                "meetup": 1,
                "user": 2


            }),
        }).then(rsvp => {
            console.log(rsvp);
           // alert(rsvp.message)
        }).catch(err => err);

    }




    render() {
        // console.log(this.state.meetups)
        return (

            <div id={styles.meetups_body}>
              <Header/>
                <div><img src={meetup_banner} className={styles.meet_bg} alt="meetups"></img> </div> 


                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <div className="row">
                    {this.state.meetups.map((meetup)=>

                        <div className="col-md-4" key={meetup.id}>
                            <div className={styles.card} style={{  marginBottom: '20px' }}>
                                <img className="card-img-top" src={meetup.image_url} alt="Card" style={{ width: '100%' }} />
                                <div align="center"> <button type="button"  className="btn" id={styles.free}>{meetup.cost}</button> </div>
                               <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}><div align="center"  > <button key={meetup.id} type="submit" onClick={() => this.handleClick(meetup.id)} className="btn" id={styles.rsvp_button} >{this.state.meetUpId == meetup.id ? 'GOING' :  'RSVP'}. </button> </div></form>  
                                <div className="card-body" style={{padding:'10px'}}>
                                    <div className="col=md-12">
                                        <div className="row">
                                            <div className="col-md-3" align="center">
                                                <h4 style={{ color: '#8cc63f', fontWeight: '600' }}>{meetup.meetup_date}</h4><br />
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col-md-9">
                                                <h5 className="card-title" style={{fontWeight:'600'}}>{meetup.title}</h5>
                                                <h6>{meetup.time}</h6> <br />
                                                <h6>{meetup.venue}</h6>
                                                <p className="card-text" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:meetup.content}} id={styles.meetup_content} style={{ textOverflow:'elipsis', width:'100%', whiteSpace:'nowrap',overflow:'hidden' }}></p>
                                                <a  href={`MeetupsDetail/${meetup.id}`} className="btn" id={styles.btn_outline_warning}>Learn More</a> <br />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="meetup_footer" >
                                        <p >{meetup.hash_tag}  </p>
                                        {/* <i className="fas fa-share-alt " id={styles.share_icon} style={{ float: 'right' }}></i> */}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        )}


                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default MeetUps;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way. Pass meetup id to handleClick method and in the handleClick event handler function set that mertup id in the state and compare this state to displace the name accordingly

Replace the below Button code in your component

```
   <button key={meetup.id} type="submit" onClick={() => this.handleClick(meetup.id)} className="btn" id={styles.rsvp_button} >{this.state.meetUpId == meetup.id ? 'GOING' :  'RSVP'}. </button>
```

Replace below function in your component

```
    handleClick(id) {
        this.setState({
           meetUpId: id
        });
    }
```

Intialize meetUpId state to 0 in constructor. This will show GOING text on Button when particular card is clicked by matching its id

Comment: Thanks again for replying me @Think-Twice when I have added your code it was showing this error "Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation): Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops." kindly help me with this

Comment: My bad. Please take the button component and try now

Comment: Its working @Think-Twice But again the issue here is like when Im clicking on particular card text is changing..the same way if im clicking on other card..previously clicked card text is reverting please help me with this..